# Linux how to delete folder based on sub folder

Tags: bash

I need to delete a series of folders on Linux based on the name of a sub folder.

```
/tmp/23245/Default
/tmp/34534/Default
/tmp/45435/Default
/tmp/65464/Main
```

I want to delete all folder off of /tmp that contains a subfolder of /Default

these folder

```
/tmp/23245/
/tmp/34534/
/tmp/45435/
```

I can find the files using: find /tmp/*/Default

But from that output, how do i get the name of the folder /tmp/Foldername to pipe to the
rm -rf

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426058/getting-the-parent-of-a-directory-in-bash

Comment: Something like `find . -type d -exec sh -c '[ -d "$1/Default" ]' - {} \; -exec rm -r {} \;` (**untested!**)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following using find:

```
find /tmp -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -name "*Default*" -type d -printf "%h\n" | xargs rm -R
```

Use mindepth and maxdepth to ensure that we are analysing directories 2 levels down from /tmp and then use %h to print only the leading directories. Pipe the output through to xargs rm -R to remove the leading directories.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `rm -d dirname` with a `*`?

```
rm -d /tmp/*/Default
```

Just going off this site: https://linuxize.com/post/rm-command-in-linux/

Comment: That wouldn’t delete the parent directory of `Default`.

Comment: (That site is horrible. ‘regular expressions’? Really?! Couldn’t you link to some proper documentation instead?)

Answer (score 0):

There's `dirname` in GNU coreutils:

```
for i in /tmp/*/Default; do
  rm -R "$(dirname "$i")";
done
```

Maybe there's a `find` approach as well. I'm not familiar with it so I'll leave that to you and/or the others.

EDIT: Perhaps even `rm -R "$(dirname /tmp/*/Default)"` would work